# Injecting bean in spring and mybatis configuration

Tags: spring, ibatis, mybatis

I am trying to configure mybatis with spring 3. I am getting the following error

```
 Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userMapper' is defined
```

For UserMapper interfcae I have done like this.

```
@Service("userMapper")
@Transactional
public interface UserMapper {

 // methods here

}
```

My Controller class is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
 public class LoginController
 {
static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

@Resource(name = "userMapper")
private UserMapper userMapper;

@RequestMapping("/login")
public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute User userBean){


    return new ModelAndView("login", "userBean", userBean); 

}

}
```

My spring-servelet.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">


<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.mycom.myproject" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.mycom.mydatabase.db.mybatis.sqlmap" />
</bean> 

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

So, How can I Inject the Dependency here and can access my database methods. Please let me now if any thing is not clear.

Comment: They have a great guide for spring and MyBatis here. http://www.mybatis.org/spring/sample.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your UserMapper interface, write down as below-

```
  public interface UserMapper {

//for example, saveUser will save data in your table taking User as bean
public void saveUser(User user);
}
```

then maintain a UserMapper.xml file like below-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.puneet.persistance.UserMapper">  
<insert id="saveUser" parameterType="com.puneet.spring3.beans.User">
        INSERT INTO USER (username,password) 
        VALUES (#{username},#{password})
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

In above xml file we mention queries and the interface that you are taking as reference.

in your LoginController, call your method like below-

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute(value="user")User user,BindingResult result){

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("yourjpspage");
        if(!result.hasErrors()){
            userMapper.saveUser(user);
            user = new User();

        }
        return mv;
    }
```

In last maintain all configurations in your spring-servelet.xml file.

Hope above all will help you.

Answer (score -1):

`UserMapper` is an interface and as such, can't be injected. You need to configure an implementation in your XML config.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I don't know much about Mybatis. So, how should I inject the beans here what should be service class here

Comment: This is completely unrelated to iBatis. You need to write a class that implements `UserMapper` and configure that as a bean with the id `userMapper` in your Spring XML.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I am reading an artical at {http://www.raistudies.com/spring/integrating-mybatis-3-and-spring-frameworks-part-2/} and it says "We do not have to implement the interface as MyBatis will provide proxy implementation for this"

Comment: I can't find the place where it says that. Also, is `UserMapper` in the package `com.mycom.myproject`?

Comment: You do not need to implement the interface. MyBatis will do that for you. Please read the guide here: http://www.mybatis.org/spring/sample.html