# Mybatis 3.1.1 insert function

Tags: java, database, mybatis, ibatis

I work Mybatis 3.1.1 and Postgresql 9.2. I Have Class Student (id, name). I want to insert a new record in the database and get its Id.

my code is

```
Student s=new Student();
s.setName("javagc");
studentMapper.insertSelective(s);
```

but `s.getId()` is `null`.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which database are you using?

It should work on MySql, as mentioned in these questions;
[Get the id of last inserted record in mybatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103606/get-the-id-of-last-inserted-record-in-mybatis),
[How to obtain last insert id in Oracle using MyBatis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234718/obtain-last-insert-id-in-oracle-using-mybatis)

I could not be able to make it work on my Oracle DB. So I manually took the current value of the sequence after the insertion.

```
<insert id="insertSelective" parameterType="myObject">
        <selectKey keyProperty="seq_id" order="AFTER" resultType="int">
              SELECT mySchema.myTable_seq.currval FROM dual
        </selectKey>
            INSERT INTO mySchema.myTable . . . 
</insert>
```