# MyBatis always returns 1

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I am trying to get last inserted key after insert using mybatis.

```
<insert id="insertOrUpdateUser" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id" 
  keyProperty="user.id" >
    INSERT INTO
    user (username, password)
    VALUES (
    #{user.username},
    #{user.password}
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    username       = #{user.username},
    password       = #{user.password}
</insert>
```

Looks like I have everything to get last generated id but I always get 1.What is wrong?

Comment: useGeneratedKeys="false" is working fine here.

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: No worries, just forgot. That In pojo id is updated automatically if we  use  useGeneratedKeys="true" keyColumn="id"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the id of last inserted record in mybatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103606/get-the-id-of-last-inserted-record-in-mybatis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id` automatically returned with your model's `id` field `user.id`, `1` is inserted row count

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103606/get-the-id-of-last-inserted-record-in-mybatis)

Comment: This is quite nasty if you are migrating from ibatis (ibator/abator) to mybatis generator as before the DAOs were returning the IDs but the mappers are now returning the row count