# mybatis intermediary table mapping

Tags: java, mybatis

I have the following table

class table

```
id  name     hours
1   science     3
2   math        5
```

teachers table

```
id  first_name  last_name
1   Ronald      Manlapao
2   hello       goodbye
3   elise       elise
4   me          me
```

class_teachers table

```
class_ref   teachers_ref
2                   2
1                   1
```

I would like to query in class_teachers table where in the results shows teachers names and class names. select statement is like this

```
select class.name as classname, 
       class.hours as hours, 
       teachers.first_name as teacherFirstName, 
       teachers.last_name as teacherLastName 
from class_teachers cl 
left join class on class.id = cl.class_ref  
left join teachers on teachers.id = cl.teachers_ref
```

how can I do this in myBatis? I can't declare classname and teachersnames in class_teacher table result because they are not part of it

Comment: What kind of relation you are having with these tables. I mean in table `class_teachers` you have relation between classes and teachers as one-to-one or many-to-one?

Comment: Refer to link: this might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491536/one-to-many-relation-using-mybatis-or-ibatis

Comment: a class_teacher can have one class. a class_teacher can have many teachers

Comment: Great. So you have one-to-many relation between class and teachers.
Here is perfect example from MyBatis site: http://mybatis.co.uk/index.php/2010/10/mybatis-one-to-many-mapping.html

Comment: I would like to see an example wherein the intermediary table (class_teacher) is being mapped

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="****" parameterType="map" resultType = "java.util.LinkedHashMap">

    your select query as listed

</select>
```

This will give you a List of linkedHashMap object, from which, you can get values as needed.